# Is it possible to reuse bits code between custom Mailchimp templates?

Tags: templates, mailchimp

I have multiple Mailchimp templates. They are for different types of campaigns so the main content and their editable areas are quite different, but they still share a lot. For example, the header and the footer are the same, and also most of the css style.

Is there a way to share the common parts between the template? Like having partials, basically.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: no, not at all.

Comment: Do you have any progress in that, please?

Comment: sadly no. I'm not actively working on Mailchimp templates, but I would still be interested in a solution